# Adding shipping rate to checkout session results in "invalid array" exception

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am creating a checkout session where I want to add shipping rate which I've created in Stripe Dashboard.

This is my code:

```
$charge = $stripeClient->checkout->sessions->create([
        'payment_method_types' => ['card', 'sepa_debit', 'giropay', 'sofort', 'alipay'],
        'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
        'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
        'shipping_address_collection' => [
          'allowed_countries' => ['DE'],
        ],

        'shipping_options' => [
          'shipping_rate' => [env('SHIPPING_KEY')],
        ],
        
        'line_items' => [$lineItems],
        'automatic_tax' => [
          'enabled' => true,
        ],
        'mode' => 'payment',
        'allow_promotion_codes' => true,
      ]);
```

But it gives an error that the array is invalid.

If I comment `shipping_options` it works...

What is wrong here?

Comment: What is generating the error and where does it occur? Perhaps a copy of the exact error might tell us?

Comment: If you run `php artisan tinker` in the console and then check for `echo env('SHIPPING_KEY')` (in the tinker console) does it show the appropriate value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your code is just passing a single hash for `shipping_options` instead of an array, so instead of this:

```
        'shipping_options' => [
          'shipping_rate' => [env('SHIPPING_KEY')],
        ],
```

you need to move the brackets to look like this:

```
        'shipping_options' => [
          ['shipping_rate' => env('SHIPPING_KEY'),],
        ],
```

Comment: Of course!!! It must be an array of hashes... -.- ... Thanks!